# How to calculate Total Follower on Facebook when called through REST api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, metrics

I am looking for an alternative way to calculate facebook page followers. As per facebook api documentation, there is no such metrics available as of now.

Let me know if anyone has encountered any solutions to it
Thanks
Harsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the total number of people who **like** the page, there is the field `fan_count`, that you can get with this query :

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}?fields=fan_count
```

If you want the total number of people who **follow** the page, there is no field to do this, according to the doc : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/

Comment: Is there any workaround? since when we export insights data manually, we get metrics as 'Total Follower', 'Daily new follow',;Daily new unfollow' etc.

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook. if there is no way with the api, then there is just no way, and no workaround.